# margin auto not determined by width

Tags: html, css

In my rails app I have a container that holds from 1 to 4 divs that contain product images/text. There is 1 div if someone only selected 1 product in the previous page, 2 divs if someone selected 2 products, 3 div's if someone selected 3 products and so one. So the amount of product div's will varies and change depending on circumstance.

What I want:
the container and its div's to be centered.

if there is one div, I want that to be centered/margin:auto,
if there are two div's I want them to float/inline-block and margin centered, 
I want all div's to be float and be centered but until all the div's fill the width of the container.

I tried to margin:auto the container, but I need a set width. If I have a set width then it wont grow depending on how many div's are in the container.

[image1 http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201312101150184_div1.png](http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201312101150184_div1.png)

[image2 http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201312101150184_div2.png](http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201312101150184_div2.png)

[image3 http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201312101150184_div3.png](http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/3201312101150184_div3.png)

width of div's inside container do not change.

My question has nothing to do with the width of the browser.

Comment: Is the container going to be the same width at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align` on the container if your insider `div` are `inline-block`:

```
.container {
   text-align:center;
}
.container div.inside {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display` to `inline-block` for the divs and `text-align` to `center` for the container.

Just remember that `text-align` is inherited, so you'll need to re-set it to the desired value on the divs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of doing this is to use

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the divs, and it's container. Do not use

```
float: left;
```

and set

```
text-align: center;
```

on the container and it's parent.

`margin: auto;` can only center a div if it has an explicit width. A div that auto-grows does not have an explicit width and so `margin: auto;` won't work.

### White space

Be careful when using `inline-block` as the browser will see whitespace in your markup and render it to the page, which can cause unwanted effects. Just make sure to trim out all the white-space between your `divs`.